# Training CNN Data (Value error in model.fit)

Tags: python, conv-neural-network

Trying to train the model but it stops at the end of training the first epoch.
Tried adding time.sleep(0.1) but that didn't work.
Code  :

```
X_train, X_test, y_train , y_test = train_test_split(data, labels, test_size = 0.2 , random_state = 42)

print(X_train.shape, X_test.shape, y_train.shape, y_test.shape)

y_train = to_categorical(y_train,43)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size = (5,5), activation= 'relu', input_shape = X_train.shape[1:])) 
model.add(Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size = (5,5), activation= 'relu'))
model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size= (2,2)))
model.add(Dropout(rate= 0.25))
model.add(Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size = (3,3), activation= 'relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(filters = 64, kernel_size = (3,3) , activation = 'relu'))
model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(Dropout(rate=0.25))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(256, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dropout(rate = 0.5)  )
model.add(Dense(43, activation = 'softmax'))
model.compile(loss= 'categorical_crossentropy', optimizer = 'adam' , metrics = ['accuracy'])

epochs = 15
history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=32, epochs=epochs,verbose = 1  ,validation_data=(X_test, y_test))
time.sleep(0.1)
model.save("my_model.h5")
```

error  :

```
Epoch 1/15
980/981 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.4359 - accuracy: 0.8742
```

---

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
 <ipython-input-8-aa8cc327989f> in <module>
      1 epochs = 15
----> 2 history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=32, epochs=epochs,verbose = 1,validation_data=(X_test, y_test))
    3 time.sleep(0.1)
    4 model.save("my_model.h5")
```

Comment: Is that the full error message?

Comment: No
~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py in _method_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs)
    106   def _method_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
    107     if not self._in_multi_worker_mode():  # pylint: disable=protected-access
--> 108       return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
    109 
    110     # Running inside `run_distribute_coordinator` already.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved the problem, the error was that the labels in y_test wasn't converted into one hot encoding.

Changes :
Added this line

```
y_test = to_categorical(y_test, 43)
```